# Failed to reset admin pass on Mysql / plesk

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos, plesk, ioncube

I broke the admin pass in the phpmyadmin inside plesk. I broke it by editing the pass (was not intentionally), and now Plesk does not load since primary admin pass is changed.

I found this guide: http://kb.parallels.com/en/112492 but it however does not allow me to change admin pass since I get this error:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined symbol: gc_remove_zval_from_buffer
Utility to set adminstrator's password
```

I cant seem to find the problem in regards to ioncube, except for that its not compatible with php, (yet ioncube dependent applications runs just fine on the server).

So what can I do to reset the admin password? I have root access, I should be able to do anything, right?

I tried the following

- restarted plesk
- check the permisssions on /etc/psa/.psa.shadow according to here: http://blog.serverbuddies.com/how-can-i-changerepair-my-admin-account-if-the-password-in-plesk/
- mysql is running

I am stuck, hope someone knows how to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the password of MySQL user "admin" you can:

```
cp /etc/psa/.psa.shadow /etc/psa/.psa.shadow.bak # just backup
chmod 400 /etc/psa/.psa.shadow.bak # just secure backup
echo "PLACE PLAIN PASSWORD OF MySQL user ADMIN HERE" > /etc/psa/.psa.shadow
```

and check Panel.

If you don't know password of MySQL user "admin" "Resolution 2" from http://kb.parallels.com/en/112492 still should help you.

The root cause of issue "undefined symbol: gc_remove_zval_from_buffer" is maybe wrong version or corrupted ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so. I can just switch off this extension in ini file somewhere in /etc/php/ or /etc/php.d/